# Is my mx record affected if I forward my domain?

Tags: domain-forwarding, mx

My domain host (not webhost) is GoDaddy. I set up the MX record to point to Gmail. I use a free host (say `examplehost.com`) without static IP, so cannot set my A record to that `examplehost.com`. So I forwarded my domain to that `examplehost.com`, is my mx record broken? (no longer works with Gmail).

Answer (score 4):

After waiting a while, now my gmail accounts for custom domains have received emails. So I guess the answer is NO, it's not broken. 
Hope it helps someone later

Comment: DNS changes can take up to 48 hours to propagate, so that was likely your problem. You should mark your own question as the correct answer if that satisfies the question.